# Parsing XML data into RichTextBox but Only One Item Appeared in Result

Tags: c#, winforms, xml-parsing

I am working on my project, I am totally new to C# and I need to use C# to do my work. I really hope you guys can lend me a hand in the below issue. Your help will be very much appreciated!! Thanks.

I have an XML file which has two `<item>...</item>` in parent `<channel>`. I executed my code, what I get is only as below - data of one `<item>` appeared:

> Title: Re: My view of Tesco
>
> Desciption:  Stay clear of the iii IPO when it comes onto the market. 
>   3 quarters are multiples, triples, quadrupole, W-T-F.  It´s like ebay
>   a lot bidding there, is fake too.
>
> Today´s thought of the day:  Odd is that Deloitte seems to have
>   escaped headlines. Accusation it colluded with Standard Chartered on
>   regulatory report cd be Enron moment  Remember those old accountants
>   Deloitte, Mr. Hyman (RBS)? By Hardcore Uproar
>
> Date: Tue, 07 Aug 2012 14:03:00 GMT
>
> ### Author: Hardcore Uproar

My code is as below:

```
        private void btnComSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load("tsco.xml");

        XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("item"); 
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            XmlNodeList comTitle = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("title");
            XmlNodeList comDesc = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("description");
            XmlNodeList comDate = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("pubDate");
            XmlNodeList comAuthor = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("creator");

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.AppendLine("Title: " + comTitle[0].InnerText + "\n");
            sb.AppendLine("Desciption: " + comDesc[0].InnerText + "\n");
            sb.AppendLine("Date: " + comDate[0].InnerText + "\n");
            sb.AppendLine("Author: " + comAuthor[0].InnerText + "\n" + "---------------" + "\n");

            richComResults.Text = sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

My XML file:

```
<channel>
<item>
      <title>Re: My view of Tesco</title>
      <description>
         <![CDATA[ Stay clear of the iii IPO when it comes onto the market.  3 quarters are multiples, triples, quadrupole, W-T-F.  It´s like ebay a lot bidding there, is fake too.Today´s thought of the day:  Odd is that Deloitte seems to have escaped headlines. Accusation it colluded with Standard Chartered on regulatory report cd be Enron moment  Remember those old accountants Deloitte, Mr. Hyman (RBS)? By Hardcore Uproar ]]>
      </description> 
      <pubDate>Tue, 07 Aug 2012 14:03:00 GMT</pubDate>
      <creator>Hardcore Uproar</creator>
</item>
<item>
      <title></title>
      <description>
         <![CDATA[ Raw material inflation;
         Rising (relative) 
         wealth outside of EU.
         Increased global demand for agri-commodities due to increasing population and relative wealth of Eastern countries.
         Decoupling of subsidy from agri-production = bad for supermarkets.
         Weather problems, diminished /(ing) resources and a general plateau reached in agriculture in terms of yield achievable = limited supply.
         Over supply of supermarkets/ retailers (too much choice= supply>demand)
         Diminished disposable income; 
         General recession.
         Poor pension performance.
         Over indebtidness in UK (further compounded by any increases in interest rates required to curb inflation).

         All this is bad news for supermarkets.. in my locality in a farily small town of 14,000 people we have a large ASDA, huge TESCO and M and S and numerous discounters.. they must be counting on all 14000 of those people visiting ALL of their local supermarkets at least 9 times a week IMHO!!
          By t8vet ]]>
       </description>
      <pubDate>Mon, 06 Aug 2012 18:47:00 GMT</pubDate>
      <creator>t8vet</creator>
</item>
</channel>
```

My Edited Code after applying your (horgh) codes:

```
private void btnComSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); //* create an xml document object.
            xmlDoc.Load("tsco.xml"); //* load the XML document from the specified file.

            XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("item"); // You can also use XPath here
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}:\t{1}", child.Name, child.FirstChild == null ? string.Empty : child.FirstChild.Value));
                richComResults.Text = sb.ToString();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

I am totally lost. I tried looking through the websites and also those were asking similar questions, but I don't really understand and I tried they don't work in my situation. I am not sure what have I done wrongly. Your help would be much appreciated :) Thank you so much.

Comment: This can be done easily by using linq-to-xml.you should try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are watching a xmlDoc, while you should watch each node. Try this:

```
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); //* create an xml document object.
        xmlDoc.Load("tsco.xml"); //* load the XML document from the specified file.

        richComResults.Text = string.Empty;

        XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("item"); // You can also use XPath here
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {                
            foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
                sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}:\t{1}", child.Name,  child.FirstChild == null ? string.Empty : child.FirstChild.Value));                
        }
        richComResults.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856125/undesired-results-appending-new-child-nodes-using-xmldocument-and-xmldocumentfra/11856259#11856259 - another post with some similar problem

Comment: Hi thanks for your feedback. But I got this warning/error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` for this line `sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}:\t{1}", child.Name, child.FirstChild.Value));`. Do you have idea what's that? Thank you.

Comment: This could happen if some of your tags were empty, say <title></title>, as the code has no validation of the format

Comment: @Shyuan Please see my answer another time, I've made some edits

Comment: you are genius and you are right there's an empty tag exactly at <title></title>. I am not supposed to edit the XML file, may I know how do I get rid of it? Thank you. Besides, I didn't get two <item></item> in my result.

Comment: @Shyuan `sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}:\t{1}", child.Name,  child.FirstChild == null ? string.Empty : child.FirstChild.Value));` just use this line of code instead the one I provided before...actually I've already fixed it in the answer text as well

Comment: the empty tag issue was fixed, thank you :) but it is still showing only one set of data. This time the data that were shown are from the second <item></item> set without showing the first <item></item> set.

Comment: @Shyuan Could you update your question with the text of the xml file you are testing + your current code?

Comment: Hi horgh, I have updated my question above. Please take a look at it. Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, i somehow got it work with the help of my friend. Yours is cool, but it is not exactly what I need. :| Sorry for not using your code and sorry for wasting your time. Thank you Horgh.